# How to build Google Analytics 'collect' like api using Google Cloud services

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to build a data collection web endpoint.The Use case is similar to Google Analytics collect API. I want to add this endpoint(GET method) to all pages on the website and on-page load collect page info through this API.

Actually I'm thinking of doing this by using Google Cloud services like Endpoints, BQ(for storing the data).. I don't want to host it in any dedicated servers. Otherwise, I will be end up doing a lot for managing/monitoring the service.

Please suggest me how do I achieve this with Google Cloud Service? OR direct me to right direction if my idea is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I suggest focussing on deciding where you want to code to run. There are several GCP options that don't require dedicated servers:

- [Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/)
- [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/)/[Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/)
- [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/) (new!)

Look [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/choose-endpoints-option#choosing_a_computing_option) to see which support Cloud Endpoints.

All of these products can support running code that takes the data from the request and sends it to the BigQuery API.

Comment: Thanks David! My biggest doubt here is ,endpoint that I'm trying to build has to be simple GET method without any authentication(oauth/token..etc). Only then I can add this endpoint on website pages and receive page information via GET request. Just similar to Google Analytics collect API. Can I achieve this with your suggestions?

Comment: All of these are able to create a handler for simple GETs. If you don't need auth, rate limiting, complex API objects etc then you won't even need cloud endpoints (or equivalent) - just write a handler to get that from the request and pass on to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways of achieving what you want. David's answer is absolutely valid, but I would like to introduce [Stackdriver Custom Metrics](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/) to the discussion.

Custom metrics are similar to regular Stackdriver Monitoring metrics, but you [create](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics) your own time series ([Stackdriver lingo described here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/metrics)) to keep track of whatever you want and clients can sent in their data through an [API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/create).

You could achieve the same thing with a compute solution (Google Cloud Functions for example) and a database (Google BigTable for example) and writing your own logic.. but Custom Metrics is an already built solution that includes [dashboards](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/) and [alerting policies](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/) while being a more managed solution.